# Query last item in a related list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have model.py that looks like

```
class Node(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    org_env = models.ForeignKey(OrgEnv)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Run(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    node = models.ForeignKey(Node)

    job_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arguments = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    return_code = models.IntegerField()
    run_time = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
```

Each node can have many runs and I'd like a query to pull out all nodes and their last run based on created date.

Comment: Great, what have you tried/researched?

Comment: try this query = Node.objects.all().order_by(-run__created)

Comment: The created is for the Run model